# Android resources - Retrieving a random voice line from a voicepack

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

For a little game I'm programming I'm trying to supply the user with some voice lines for flavor reasons. I've already recorded several lines, and they're all in the format of `languageCode_packageName_name01.mp3`.

Since I don't want the same few lines to play all the time, I intend to record several versions, and randomly pick one when retrieving them. For example, retrieving lines for "start" two times could result in playback of `de_std_start01` and then `de_std_start06`.

Since I am quite new to android I'd like to ask for help regarding this implementation. I'm not sure whether I should utilize the raw folder for this task, or the assets folder. If possible, I would like to implement a folder structure like this, which would to my understanding need the use of the assets folder, in order to be able to simply drag & drop new files inside the folder, which will then be taken into account for random selection.:

```
<root folder>
- de
-- std
--- start
---- start01.mp3
---- start02.mp3
...
```

When given arguments specifying `de`, `std` and `start`, how would I go about retrieving the different files and randomly pick one of them? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include them in the raw folder, you should be able to access them as so:

```
//from your activity

AudioService audioService = new AudioService;
int randomTune = audioService.getRandom();
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, randomTune);
mediaplayer.start;

//From a seperate service class

Class AudioService {

    private int[] audioFiles = {
        R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2, R.raw.song3, R.raw.song4, R.raw.song5, R.raw.song6
    };
```

I believe that your folder structure will be somewhat flexible since you are wrapping the actual resource with the R class and referencing that in your code.

```
public int getRandom(){
  // Here i am asking for a random number between 0 and 1, multiplying by 6, rounding 
  // it down, and explicitly casting to int.
  // Result will be random int between 0 and 5. This will be the array index that 
  // randomly chooses the song.  
    private int randomIndex;
    randomindex = (int) Math.floor(6 * Math.random);
    return this.audioFiles[randomIndex];
}
```

}

Comment: Thank your for your quick answer! I think that approach will lead to great results, I'm going to implement it over the next few days and provide feedback!